# How to initialize an activity from another activity

Tags: android

I have activities A and B. Activity B is started by a service while the application is closed and activity A is not on the stack. Activity A has members that B requires access to. I would also like the home button to open activity A from Activity B even if activity B is started from a service. Is there a way to inject activity A back into the stack?

Comment: `Activity A has members that B requires access to` that is a problem in the app architecture. It should not be this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Service` start `ActivityA` not `ActivityB` and pass some parameter to `ActivityA`.. and in `ActivityA`'s `OnCraete` method launch the `ActivityB`.. now you have both in the stack.

Comment: I like that idea, let me try it

Comment: But what if activity is A is already open, would I be adding another main activity on the stack?

Comment: I don't know what is your application flow..But, it depends on the structure of the app, in what case you r starting the activity. BTW you can make an activity single instance. or you can check whether the activity is in the foreground of not.

Comment: Yes, I made activity A single instance, and pass a bundle to it from the Service, which I can still do. I check if the bundle is not null in activity A, and if it's not I open the activity B. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the logical parent of each activity in your manifest file, using the android:parentActivityName attribute (and corresponding  element),for home button working.

And to add a activity back to stack
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415711/4604095) for more details.

Comment: I already had that attribute in my xml. I don't think it's working as your described.

Comment: have you override your home button onclick ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207762/must-i-specify-the-parent-activity-name-in-the-android-manifest

Answer (score 0):

That won't be a good decision, better use the members in the B Activity and Once Activity B is launched and it's about to leave just give intent to Activity A.
Also you can check if Activity A is already in the stack. If already in the stack, it will popup by itself, if not found, can pro grammatically trigger it.

Comment: SRB had a good idea about starting activity A from activity B but what if activity A is already on the stack?

Comment: There is a routine to check the stack. Else you can use a flag in the Activity A's life cycle!